# I/art Info error logs while implementing Admob

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, webview, admob

I'm getting a bunch of I/art info logs when I run my app with Admob using an emulator, one of them points to MobileAds.initialize() line. These are just info logs and my test ad runs just fine. Should I be worried?

I've tried the following to resolve but no luck so far:
Clean, Rebuild, Invalidate cache and restart.

Code inside onCreate():

````
MobileAds.initialize(this)
        val adRequest: AdRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
        RewardedAd.load(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917",
            adRequest, object : RewardedAdLoadCallback() {
                override fun onAdFailedToLoad(loadAdError: LoadAdError) {
                    // Handle the error.
                    Log.d(TAG, loadAdError.message)
                    mRewardedAd = null
                }

                override fun onAdLoaded(rewardedAd: RewardedAd) {
                    mRewardedAd = rewardedAd

                    mRewardedAd!!.setFullScreenContentCallback(object : FullScreenContentCallback() {
                        override fun onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                            // Called when ad is shown.
                            Log.d(TAG, "Ad was shown.")
                        }

                        override fun onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(adError: AdError) {
                            // Called when ad fails to show.
                            Log.d(TAG, "Ad failed to show.")
                        }

                        override fun onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                            // Called when ad is dismissed.
                            // Set the ad reference to null so you don't show the ad a second time.
                            Log.d(TAG, "Ad was dismissed.")
                            mRewardedAd = null
                        }
                    })

                    Log.d(TAG, "Ad was loaded.")
                }
            })```


Here are info logs:
```I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<uJ>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/webkit/TracingController;
I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.classForName!(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Class.java:-2)
I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.forName(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Class.java:400)
I/art:     at java.lang.Class android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProviderClass() (WebViewFactory.java:349)
I/art:     at android.webkit.WebViewFactoryProvider android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider() (WebViewFactory.java:194)
I/art:     at android.webkit.WebViewFactoryProvider android.webkit.WebView.getFactory() (WebView.java:2325)
I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.ensureProviderCreated() (WebView.java:2320)
I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(int) (WebView.java:2379)
I/art:     at void android.view.View.<init>(android.content.Context) (View.java:4023)
I/art:     at void android.view.View.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (View.java:4146)
I/art:     at void android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (ViewGroup.java:579)
I/art:     at void android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (AbsoluteLayout.java:55)
I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int, java.util.Map, boolean) (WebView.java:627)
I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (WebView.java:572)
I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int) (WebView.java:555)
I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (WebView.java:542)
I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context) (WebView.java:532)
I/art:     at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcpi.<init>(com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcqd, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcqe, java.lang.String, boolean, boolean, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzalt, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbmi, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcjf, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbly, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzl, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zza, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbay, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzfdn, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzfdq) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@20.6.0:1)
I/art:     at java.lang.Object com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcoy.zza() (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@20.6.0:4)
I/art:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcop com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcpb.zza(android.content.Context, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcqe, java.lang.String, boolean, boolean, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzalt, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbmi, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcjf, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbly, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzl, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zza, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbay, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzfdn, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzfdq) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@20.6.0:8)
I/art:     at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbuw.<init>(android.content.Context, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcjf, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzalt, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zza) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@20.6.0:3)
I/art:     at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbvt.zzi(com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzalt, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbvs) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@20.6.0:1)
I/art:     at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbvc.run() (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@20.6.0:-1)
I/art:     at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcjj.execute(java.lang.Runnable) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@20.6.0:2)
I/art:     at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcjl.execute(java.lang.Runnable) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@20.6.0:1)
I/art:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbvs com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbvt.zzd(com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzalt) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@20.6.0:2)
I/art:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbvn com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbvt.zzb(com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzalt) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@20.6.0:4)
I/art:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzfxa com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbwl.zzb(java.lang.Object) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@20.6.0:2)
I/art:     at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zze.zzb(android.content.Context, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcjf, boolean, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcif, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.Runnable) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@20.6.0:26)
I/art:     at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zze.zza(android.content.Context, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcjf, java.lang.String, java.lang.Runnable) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@20.6.0:1)
I/art:     at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcuu.zzk(java.lang.String, com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@20.6.0:15)
I/art:     at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbjq.zzl(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.OnInitializationCompleteListener) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@20.6.0:13)
I/art:     at void com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds.initialize(android.content.Context) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@20.6.0:2)
I/art:     at void com.jayengames.la.AndroidLauncher.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (AndroidLauncher.kt:120)
I/art:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6679)
I/art:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1118)
I/art:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2618)
I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2726)
I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1477)
I/art:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
I/art:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6119)
I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:886)
I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:776)
I/art: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.webkit.TracingController" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/app/Chrome/Chrome.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/app/Chrome/lib/x86, /system/app/Chrome/Chrome.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
I/art:     at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.classForName!(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Class.java:-2)
I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.forName(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Class.java:400)
I/art:     at java.lang.Class android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProviderClass() (WebViewFactory.java:349)
I/art:     at android.webkit.WebViewFactoryProvider android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider() (WebViewFactory.java:194)
I/art:     at android.webkit.WebViewFactoryProvider android.webkit.WebView.getFactory() (WebView.java:2325)
I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.ensureProviderCreated() (WebView.java:2320)
I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(int) (WebView.java:2379)
I/art:     at void android.view.View.<init>(android.content.Context) (View.java:4023)
I/art:     at void android.view.View.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (View.java:4146)
I/art:     at void android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (ViewGroup.java:579)
I/art:     at void android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (AbsoluteLayout.java:55)
I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int, java.util.Map, boolean) (WebView.java:627)
I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (WebView.java:572)
I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int) (WebView.java:555)
I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (WebView.java:542)
I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context) (WebView.java:532)
I/art:     at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcpi.<init>(com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcqd, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcqe, java.lang.String, boolean, boolean, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzalt, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbmi, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcjf, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbly, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzl, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zza, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbay, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzfdn, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzfdq) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@20.6.0:1)
I/art:     at java.lang.Object com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcoy.zza() (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@20.6.0:4)
I/art:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcop com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcpb.zza(android.content.Context, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcqe, java.lang.String, boolean, boolean, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzalt, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbmi, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcjf, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbly, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzl, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zza, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbay, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzfdn, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzfdq) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@20.6.0:8)
I/art:     at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbuw.<init>(android.content.Context, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcjf, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzalt, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zza) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@20.6.0:3)
I/art:     at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbvt.zzi(com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzalt, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbvs) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@20.6.0:1)
I/art:     at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbvc.run() (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@20.6.0:-1)
I/art:     at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcjj.execute(java.lang.Runnable) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@20.6.0:2)
I/art:     at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcjl.execute(java.lang.Runnable) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@20.6.0:1)
I/art:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbvs com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbvt.zzd(com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzalt) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@20.6.0:2)
I/art:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbvn com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbvt.zzb(com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzalt) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@20.6.0:4)
I/art:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzfxa com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbwl.zzb(java.lang.Object) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@20.6.0:2)
I/art:     at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zze.zzb(android.content.Context, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcjf, boolean, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcif, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.Runnable) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@20.6.0:26)
I/art:     at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zze.zza(android.content.Context, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcjf, java.lang.String, java.lang.Runnable) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@20.6.0:1)
I/art:     at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcuu.zzk(java.lang.String, com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@20.6.0:15)
I/art:     at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbjq.zzl(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.OnInitializationCompleteListener) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@20.6.0:13)
I/art:     at void com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds.initialize(android.content.Context) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@20.6.0:2)
I/art:     at void com.jayengames.la.AndroidLauncher.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (AndroidLauncher.kt:120)
I/art:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6679)
I/art:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1118)
I/art:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2618)
I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2726)
I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1477)
I/art:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
I/art:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6119)
I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:886)
I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:776)```
````

Comment: "Should I be worried?" -- no, not about `I/art` log messages.

Comment: @JayN have you used `MobileAds.initialize(this)` in any other activity? or In only this `Activity`?

Comment: Only 1 in AndroidLauncher, under onCreate()